# 'Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list' error occurs when i execute webview loadUrl ()

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

```
private String getMeaningJavascript = "javascript:JavaScriptInterface.getMeaning (function test() {return 'hi';} test();)";
...
this.loadUrl(getMeaningJavascript);
...
public class JavaScriptInterface {

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void getWord(String text){
        wordAndMeaning += text;
        Log.w("test",text);
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void getMeaning(String text) {
        Log.w("test",text);
    }

}
```

This is my javascript code to execute.

And my interface's getMeaning function just print hi.

I don't think there is problem with my javascript code.

but i don't know why this error occurs.

Comment: This is invalid javascript: `javascript:JavaScriptInterface.getMeaning (function test() {return 'hi';} test();)` If it is supposed to be a string, you are missing the quotes

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Technically it is valid given it is a URL.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that you are missing quotes around your string. Your method `getMeaning` takes a string, however you are not passing a string to it. By wrapping the passed value within quotes to `getMeaning` the error should go away.

**Note:** My Java isn't up to par, but it should look something like this:

```
private String getMeaningJavascript = 
  "javascript:JavaScriptInterface.getMeaning (\"function test() {return 'hi';} test();\")";
```

Comment: thanks but i want to pass 'hi' to getMeaning function. but your answer print ''function test() {return 'hi';} test();".

Comment: It is printing that because you are telling it to: `Log.w("test",text);`

Comment: i did not explain in detail. I want to run the JavaScript function and get the returned text as an argument to the getMeaning function. For example, this is another code that passes the querySelector value to the getword function. 

        `this.loadUrl("javascript:JavaScriptInterface.getWord(document.querySelector(\"html body#bodyClass div#content div.entry_search_word.top div.h_word._tipSkipItem strong.target\").innerHTML)");`